# How do I check a persons email address to make sure they have a paypal account?

Tags: cakephp, paypal

I'm trying to advance my programming skills and as such I'm trying to create a website which integrates with paypal. I've established that I need to be using chained payments through the adaptive payments API.

But before I go about receiving and sending payments I want to make sure that any new user signing up to my website already has a paypal account. IE when they sign up to my website I'd like to first of all check that the email address they supplied me with is already linked to a valid paypal account.

I've never had to do this before so if someone could explain in very simple language how I might go about doing this I'd be really grateful.

I'm using the cakephp framework incase that makes any difference to the answer.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for: [AddressVerify API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_AddressVerify)

> Confirms whether a postal address and postal code match those of the
>   specified PayPal account holder.

After supplying an email address, PayPal will return with one of 3 responses for the email parameter: *None*, *Confirmed*, or *Unconfirmed*. If it is *None*, then the request value does not match any email address on file at PayPal.

Although this API requires both the email address and shipping/billing information, it can be solely used to verify the email address. **By supplying invalid shipping/billing information, the API will still respond with whether the email matches any on file at PayPal**, and also match whether your invalid shipping/billing information matches the information on file with the matched email address.

An expected PayPal response may reflect the above:

```
Array
(
    [CONFIRMATIONCODE] => Confirmed
    [STREETMATCH] => Unconfirmed
    [ZIPMATCH] => Unconfirmed
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [TOKEN] => a134k1j34lk134gv13dshjg52b
)
```

`CONFIRMATIONCODE` will be your only concern when verifying a PayPal email address.

Please, check the above link for more information.

Comment: The AddressVerify API requires all three of email address, street address and postal code.

Comment: The address verify api did look exactly like what I was after, until I read richie's comment. Is that true, you need all three? If so is there anything else which only requires email address? thanks

Comment: @Richie Although this is true, you can still use it to verify the email address. If you read the documentation, the API will still return whether the email address is on file for a PayPal account holder regardless if you enter invalid shipping/billing information. It is required, but does not hinder you from verifying a PayPal email address.

Comment: @Chase: Ah, I see I misread the documentation.  Sorry for the confusion!  Thanks for the clarification, and +1.

Comment: @Richie No, thank you! Encouraged me to provide a more informative answer.

Comment: @Chase wow, thanks for that - and sorry for only spotting it now. You're a legend! Even the guys on paypal's own forum didn't seem to have a solution for this!

Answer (score -1):

Setting up an [IPN Listener](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation) is one way that's often used to verify most of the important information you're referring to. There's a [decent tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/) that you can check out since paypal's example might not be enough on it's own.

Comment: How does that help?  As I understand it, IPN is for notification of payments.  The OP is talking about verifying an email address before attempting anything to do with payments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but Like Richie says, I need to just check the email address before anything else gets done.